# Writing custom script language

Tags: c++, c

I'm not sure if this is on the right forum but im putting it here.

I am interesting in writing my own script language that is easy to embed in any language. I want to do it for educational purposes, to see how it works and to learn more about how programming languages and script languages work and how they can work together. I am a college student learning c and c++. I am eager to learn as much as I can.

Could anybody tell me where I could find some resources or books to help me get started? What else I could do to learn the same things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for compiler-compilers.

As a dinosaur, I'd say look into flex/bison to have the full featured options (but also developer responsibilities):

http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~beardj/FlexBisonC++.html

It will certainly address the educational purposes. See that a programming language consists of a 'scanner', that tokenizes characters into words, and a parser, that combines words to expressions, statements, and complete programs.

Comment: While flex/bison certainly is certainly *the* classic option (well I used mostly lex/yacc), it's a really low-level and rather cumbersome way to approach it. If a recursive descent LL(*) parser or similar is enough, something like ANTLR or Coco/R is much more comfortable to get something quickly going. And realistically that's powerful enough for any sane grammar (so yeah c++ will be a problem).